# How can be added multiple subtitles using dash shaka-player from a .mpd file?

Tags: javascript, html, video, mpeg-dash

Summary: I do not know how to add (and to show) multiple subtitles choice in a .mpd / shaka-player.

I have set a web site to provide videos through internet, using shaka-player library, so that Google Chrome users can watch them. So, using the following tutorial I could manage to deploy a simple demo video:

```
https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/tutorial-player.html
```

In my case all the .mp4 audio and video files (which are encrypted), and also the .vtt files for the subtitles for Greek and also English (not encrypted) are in the same folder (web folder); in that folder there is also the .mpd file which is used in order to load the video, according to the tutorial mentioned above.

According to the aforementioned tutorial the .mpd file is loaded in the following way:

```
// Construct a DashVideoSource to represent the DASH manifest.
var mpdUrl = 'https://turtle-tube.appspot.com/t/t2/dash.mpd';
var estimator = new shaka.util.EWMABandwidthEstimator();
var source = new shaka.player.DashVideoSource(mpdUrl, null, estimator);
// Load the source into the Player.
player.load(source);
```

I have also added subtitles support using the following .mdp file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="static"      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011      http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-     DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd" mediaPresentationDuration="PT7120S"      maxSegmentDuration="PT10S" minBufferTime="PT10S"      profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011"      xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011">
   <Period>
     <AdaptationSet mimeType="video/mp4" minBandwidth="247684" maxBandwidth="848398" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
       <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="video" />
       <SegmentTemplate initialization="Video$RepresentationID$.mp4"  media="Video$RepresentationID$-$Number$.mp4" duration="10" startNumber="1" />
       <Representation id="0" bandwidth="247684" codecs="avc1.42c01e" />
       <Representation id="1" bandwidth="511973" codecs="avc1.42c01e" />
       <Representation id="2" bandwidth="848398" codecs="avc1.42c01e" />
       <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" />
       <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed" />
     </AdaptationSet>
     <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" minBandwidth="65311" maxBandwidth="65311" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
       <ContentComponent id="1" contentType="audio" />
       <SegmentTemplate initialization="Audio$RepresentationID$.mp4" media="Audio$RepresentationID$-$Number$.mp4" duration="10" startNumber="1" />
       <Representation id="3" bandwidth="65311" codecs="mp4a.40.5" />
       <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc" />
       <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed" />
     </AdaptationSet>

     <AdaptationSet contentType="text" lang="el" mimeType="text/vtt">
         <Role value="main" />
         <Representation id="4" bandwidth="1000">
             <BaseURL>MySubtitle.el.vtt</BaseURL>
         </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>

    <AdaptationSet contentType="text" lang="en" mimeType="text/vtt">
        <Representation id="5" bandwidth="1000">
            <BaseURL>MySubtitle.en.vtt</BaseURL>
        </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

In a Google Chrome web browser I can play the film and I can see several controls like volume and also "CC", which means subtitles; consequently, when I press over "CC" then I can activate subtitles; however, I have configured two subtitles languages in the .mpd file (Greek and English) but pressing on the "CC" control it can only activate or deactivate the subtitles in Greek (the first .vtt subtitles file set in the .mpd file described above), but I do not know how to activate or to show a menu to select the subtitles in the different available languages.

Answer (score 0):

The aforementioned .mpd file contains two entries for two different subtitles languages and it is correct. The way to select one subtitle or the other is using the methods:

```
getTextTracks()
selectTextTrack(id)
```

That is:

```
// Load the source into the Player.
player.load(source).then(function() {
var textTracks = player.getTextTracks();
console.log("TextTrack Len: " + textTracks.length);
// Selecting the second text track got from
// getTextTracks()
player.selectTextTrack(textTracks[1].id);
video.play();
});
```

Of course, it will be necessary to add this logic to a user interface control (HTML5) so that the user can select the suitable subtitle.

It could be nice to add a new control in the tool bar of the player (where there are the controls of volume, enlarge, etc.), which performs this functionality, but I do not know how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot add more options to the toolbar of the video player; consequently you can add menu options using HTML and then call the corresponding methods of the shaka-player library; like "getTextTracks", "selectTextTrack", ...